# Using the Play Framework for Java, how do I return a 500 response from a controller?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I've inherited a Play Framework v1.2 application that serves up both a Website as well as an API. The existing error handling strategy for the API controllers uses `renderJSON(error.message)` to return errors to our client, unfortunately creating responses that return a 200.

I want to return an actual status code, 4xx or 5xx. The problem is if I use `error(message)`, that produces a 500 response, but the 500.html error page kicks in and returns HTML instead of JSON. I could override the template to render JSON but that affects our customer facing web pages.

I'm struggling to figure out how to manually set a response status code only for our API controllers, as well as render a JSON doc.

I'm pretty new to the Framework and have been looking over the docs, but for version 1.2, I don't see a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it seems to be the most direct without dealing with the larger issue of mixing a website project with an API project.

I found the source code for the Play Framework version 1.2 here, https://github.com/playframework/play1/tree/1.2.x.

I was able to find the definition of `Response` and find that status is just a field on the class. So this works as I was hoping:

```
renderJSON("{ 'status' : 'error' }");
response.status = Http.StatusCode.INTERNAL_ERROR;
```

Comment: One thing to watch out for here is that renderJSON is underneath still classed as a success response even though you've overwritten the response code. If you are using Play's Hibernate/JPA then you may find that it wont rollback any database changes already in progress when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `renderJSON()` throws `RenderJson` exception internally, so the status code have to be set before calling it.

```
response.status = Http.StatusCode.INTERNAL_ERROR;
renderJSON(theJsonObject);
```